# Powershell Foreach Loop finds file names, but returns that they don't exist

Tags: powershell, gnupg

Here is the relevant excerpt of my code:

```
$CurDir = Split-Path $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Get-ChildItem -Path $CurDir -Filter TestFile*.txt | foreach { 
    gpg --recipient "RecipName" --encrypt $_ }
```

However, this is what is returned:

```
gpg: can't open `TestFileForENcryption - Copy (2).txt': No such file or  direct
gpg: TestFileForENcryption - Copy (2).txt: encryption failed: No such file or
gpg: can't open `TestFileForENcryption - Copy (3).txt': No such file or direct
gpg: TestFileForENcryption - Copy (3).txt: encryption failed: No such file or
gpg: can't open `TestFileForENcryption - Copy.txt': No such file or directory
gpg: TestFileForENcryption - Copy.txt: encryption failed: No such file or dire
gpg: can't open `TestFileForENcryption.txt': No such file or directory
gpg: TestFileForENcryption.txt: encryption failed: No such file or directory
```

If it's able to locate each of these file's to get the names during GCI, why is it saying that they don't exist when trying to perform an action on them?
Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$CurDir = Split-Path $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Get-ChildItem -Path $CurDir -Filter TestFile*.txt | foreach { 
    gpg --recipient "RecipName" --encrypt $_.FullName }
```

I believe your error was simply it having `$_`, which only gives the name of the file, as opposed to the FQPN (fully qualified path name).

See [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/feda7c97-f9c0-400b-92c1-750bbd061855/difference-between-the-name-and-fullname-property?forum=winserverpowershell) for details as to how Name/FullName are utilized differently.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely because those files aren't in the working directory of `gpg`. Try telling it the full path of the files by using the `FullName` property:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $CurDir -Filter TestFile*.txt | foreach { 
    gpg --recipient "RecipName" --encrypt "$($_.FullName)" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  My problem was two fold:  When manually testing this snippet I was doing so from the wrong directory which explains the "No such file or directory" I was getting.
  It wasn't running from task scheduler (what I was troubleshooting to begin with) because when importing the key for something that's going to be run unattended in gnupg you must use the --home-directory command before --import.